# In ngx-echarts, is there a way to configure the legend icon inactive state?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

I'm configuring the legend of my scatter chart using ngx-echarts. Instead of a fixed symbol to represent my data series in the legend, I would like to display an icon that represents a checked checkbox when active and an unchecked checkbox when inactive.

I achieved the first one using the "icon" parameter:

```
this.chartOption = {
  legend: {
   data: {
      name: 'serie1',
      icon: 'path://m419-321 289-290-43-43-246 247-119-119-43 43 162 162ZM180-120q-24 0-42-18t-18-42v-600q0-24 18-42t42-18h600q24 0 42 18t18 42v600q0 24-18 42t-42 18H180Z'
      },
   data: {
      name: 'serie2',
      icon: 'path://m419-321 289-290-43-43-246 247-119-119-43 43 162 162ZM180-120q-24 0-42-18t-18-42v-600q0-24 18-42t42-18h600q24 0 42 18t18 42v600q0 24-18 42t-42 18H180Z'
      }
   }
}
```

But, while the documentation mentions inactiveColor, inactiveBorderColor etc. to configure the behaviour of the legend when inactive, I don't see an equivalent for the icon (like "inactiveIcon").

Is there anything I've missed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`legendselectchanged`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.legendselectchanged) event to dynamically change the icon (or any other) properties of the legend.

Assuming that you set the svg path in a string and create the echarts instance `myChart` by the standard recipe:

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
    renderer: 'canvas',
    useDirtyRect: false
});

const iconCheckedPath = 'path://m419-321 289-290-43-43-246 247-119-119-43 43 162 162ZM180-120q-24 0-42-18t-18-42v-600q0-24 18-42t42-18h600q24 0 42 18t18 42v600q0 24-18 42t-42 18H180Z';
```

with the initial `legend` option as

```js
const option = {
    // ........ other options
    legend: {
        data: [{
                name: 'serie1',
                icon: iconCheckedPath
            },
            {
                name: 'serie2',
                icon: iconCheckedPath
            }
        ],
        // .....        
    }
    // ....
};
myChart.setOption(option);
```

you may set the event handler as

```js
myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function ({selected}) {
    myChart.setOption({
        legend:{
            data: Object.entries(selected)
                .map(([name, nameSelected]) =>
                    ({name, icon: nameSelected ? iconCheckedPath: 'square'}))
        }
    })
});
```

Here's a working example in a [codesandbox](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/YzRyNGg?editors=0010), forked from one of echart's standard examples.

In case there are other options in `legend.data`, one may merge them with the new options with something on the lines of

```js
myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function ({selected}) {
    const actualData = myChart.getOption().legend[0].data;
    Object.entries(selected).forEach(([name, nameSelected])=>{
      const dataObj = actualData.find(({name: actualName})=>actualName === name);
      if(dataObj){
        dataObj.icon = nameSelected ? iconCheckedPath: 'square';
      }
    });
    myChart.setOption({
        legend:{
            data: actualData
        }
    })
});
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/zYMvpgG?editors=0010) example with that.

Comment: This works brilliantly! The only issue left is that map function overrides the other parameters that were defined in the legend property - itemStyle and textStyle. Do you know of any way to maintain them as they are?

Comment: The function `setOption` typically merges (by default) the existing options with the new ones, but it seems it doesn't work for arrays. I added a version that merges the options in `legend.data`  manually.

Comment: This is awesome. It wasn't working initially - I was receiving an error saying `the legend property comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['legend']`. But I found a fix in another stackoverflow thread (changing a parameter in tsconfig.json) that did the trick. It works brilliantly now. Thanks for the quick and super helpful answers, kikon.